# Where to download tkinter for python 2.7? My target machine has no Internet Connection

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I can't find `tkinter` on `pypi` or anywhere else.  I've read that it comes with python 2.7, but it is not on beaglebone debian.

I don't have an Internet connection for it so I need to transfer the files and install manually.

Can someone show me a link to tkinter?  And also an explanation as to why I can't find it, and why for example `py-serial` was easy to find?  eg. googling `py-serial download` has the correct 1st result.  `tkinter` is nowhere to be found.

Installing the debian package works, but I'm looking for the python solution, not the debian solution.  ie. where did the debian package get the files from?

Thanks

Comment: You may be able to build if from source code, specifically `tkinter.h` and `_tkinter.c`. The source for Python 2.7.17 can be obtained from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2717).

Comment: This page might help: https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html

Comment: Does this [`link`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/python-tk) help?

Comment: usually it is installed with Python. On Python 2 it uses different names so you have to use `import Tkinter` instead of `import tkinter`. Once I saw Python without `tkinter` on Ubuntu  and it would need to install it using `apt install python-tk`